# Issue with a texture

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to texture a capacitor and my top part has a separate material slot. When I assign a new material, the old one is still somehow showing in form of triangles.
Why is that?

There's nothing in the UV map that would do it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). This looks like a result of Subdivision surface modifier on the top n-gon.

Comment: That's it! How do I keep the subsurf, but have a clean texture in this case?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the wireframe of the model  itelf not just the uv wireframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of a Subdivision Modifier on an n-gon.
Just add another loop, and assign the white color to it as well.

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you! <3

Comment: Glad to be of help :).